# JBOSS/Wildfly 21 org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

We are migrating up to Wildfly 21 from 8 & 9 and I am having some issues getting the persistence unit working. Here is the full error:

```
13:47:29,524 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit.”projectName.war#ertDatasource": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."projectName.war#ertDatasource": java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:198)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:128)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:659)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1250)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:170)
    ... 10 more

13:47:29,587 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "projectName.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"projectName.war#ertDatasource\"" => "java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError"}}
```

So, some issue starting the persistence unit.

Here is my persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="ertDatasource">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ERT</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I forget which version of Wildfly started this trend, but they are shipping with the Jakarta Persistence libs now. As is default I have the jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar as well as the module.xml files located in the `wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/javax/persistence/api/main` folder

Here is the content of the module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module name="javax.persistence.api" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.7">
    <dependencies>
        <!-- PersistenceUnitInfo needs javax.sql.DataSource -->
        <module name="javax.api" export="true"/>
    </dependencies>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar"/>
    </resources>
</module>
```

Here is all the pom.xml's data on hibernate.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.9.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

So, that is likely where things went wrong, am I missing some dependencies, or should I just change the `hibernate-jpamodelgen`'s scope to provided?

In the WEB-INF/lib i have:
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final, hibernate-jpamodelgen-4.3.9.Final, and hibernate-validator-5.0.1.Final

Wondering what might be misconfigured here?

Comment: Do you have hibernate in your lib folder ?

Comment: @ehsavoie I forget which version of Wildfly started this trend, but they are shipping with the Jakarta Persistence libs now. As is default I have the jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar as well as the module.xml files located in the wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/javax/persistence/api/main folder

Comment: @ehsavoie I have added the module.xml content to the posting

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with the module. Are you including Hibernate in your deployment?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Honestly, I'm not that familiar with the config or deploy process. How would i tell if Hibernate is in my deployment?

Comment: How do you do your build? If you use maven you'll want to make sure any Hibernate dependencies are configured with `<scope>provided</scope>`. You should be able to inspect your WAR and see if there are any libraries in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Here is all the pom.xml's data on hibernate.

`
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
`

So, that is likely where things went wrong.
In the WEB-INF/lib i have:
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final, hibernate-jpamodelgen-4.3.9.Final, and hibernate-validator-5.0.1.Final

Comment: Yes. Try marking those dependencies as `<scope>provided</scope>` as they are provided by the container.